# AWSのVPCを設定しないとどのようなことが起こりますか？

Tags: aws

現状で、EC2にVPCを設定していなくてデフォルトにしています、
AWSのコンソールでVPCを作成して、サブネットをVPC内に作成して、インスタンスに結びつけるというのをしているのですが、この設定をして、具体的に何が解決するのかが、わかりません。
VPCなどの設定をしなくても、ELB,RDS,EC2がつながっていて問題なく運用できているので、どのような意味があるのでしょうか？ネットで調べても記事はでてきますが、イメージができないです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

現状で問題なく利用できているのであれば、無理して VPC に移行する必要はないと思います。
VPC にするメリットは下記があげられます。

- VPN や Direct Connect で社内LANと接続することができる。  
  (いわゆる、プライベートクラウドとして利用)
- インターネットから直接接続できないサブネットを作成することができる。
  (例: Webサーバーを公開ネットワークに、DBサーバーを内部ネットワークに置く)
- サブネットごとのルーティングや ネットワークACL を設定することができる。
- セキュリティグループで inbound だけでなく、outbound も設定できる。
- EC2インスタンスのローカルIPアドレスを固定にすることができる。
- EC2インスタンスにローカルIPアドレスを複数設定できる。
  (OS 側で IPエイリアス設定が必要)
- ハードウェア専有オプションが選べる
- T2, M4 などの新しいインスタンスクラスを選べる

サブネット構成がとれるので、従来の(オンプレミスの)ネットワーク設計やセキュリティ設計の考え方をある程度流用できるということかと思います。
ただし、サブネットといっても、ブロードキャストは使えないので、オンプレミスそのままとはいきませんが。

デメリット

- セキュリティグループの数に制限がかかる。

  - VPC ごとに最大 100まで
  - 1インスタンスに最大 5 つまで
  - ルールは最大50まで